# How does plane 2=0 look in 3D?

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus

Recently I got algebra exam and there was task:

> find angle between a line (there was some normal formula for a line) and plane defined by `2=0`.

Is existence of that plane even possible, or maybe vector of a plane is just `v=[0,0,0]`?

Comment: Can you clarify what 2=0 means? Do you have the equation of the plane?

Comment: That's not a plane; the set of points $(x, y, z)$ satisfying this equation is the empty set.

Comment: @AkashPatel yes, it's equation of a plane

Comment: @TheoBendit so what's the answer? Could i wrote ` it's unsolvable `?

Comment: Are you sure it isn't the plane whose equation is $z=0$?

Comment: @DrFreeman Possibly. You could possibly say, "that's not a plane". The question is not really well-posed.

Comment: Think about what that equation is saying... all it is is an incorrect statement

Comment: @BernardMassé I'm sure, that's why i was surprised

Comment: Maybe the plane was $z=0$?